# run jenkins as user "hudson"

Tags: hudson, jenkins

we've updated hudson to jenkins and have a few dependencies upon the "hudson" user we used to have.

Now that we have jenkins running (works fine) we'd like it to run as the user "hudson" in order to keep our other processes intact without having to rewrite them.

We found instructions on how to do this BEFORE installing jenkins, but we're already past that point. Jenkins is installed and up and running. Is there a way to let jenkins run as the user "hudson"?

We are running CENTOS

Comment: Maybe a little bit more detailed description on how it was installed and from what kind of package might be beneficial.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins usually runs with it's own user, so there are two main issues to handle:

- Make sure user '**hudson**' has **full access** to the files of user '**jenkins**' (or whatever user it was set to run as).
- Start the Jenkins-daemon (or other initiator) with the 'hudson' user.

(another approach is to change the user-ID so it is actually the same user but with two names)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you've installed Jenkins from RPM, there should be an /etc/sysconfig/jenkins file with a JENKINS_USER setting that defaults to 'jenkins' that you can change to 'hudson'.

I second Gonen's comment above about making sure you change the ownership of the 'jenkins' owned files to 'hudson'.  Don't forget about the /var/log/jenkins logs.

Also don't forget to restart the Jenkins service after updating the files.